# "no matching manifest for linux/amd64 in the manifest list entries" when trying to push multi-arch manifest via Github workflow

Tags: docker, github-actions, docker-registry, dockerhub

I maintain a docker image that packages a well-known comic library program. I designed this image to be multi-arch responsive, with two different versions of the bundled software (one using `p7zip` for decompression and one using `unarr`, and three different Dockerfiles per version (amd64, arm63v8, and arm32v7). I use a Github Actions workflow to build and push each image to Docker Hub and the Github Container Registry upon the creation of a new GitHub release, and then to create and push a manifest which bundles the different image tags together under the meta tags `latest`, `unarr`, `p7zip`. Until recently this workflow worked without any issues, but for some reason the `push-manifest` part of my workflow started failing with my most recent release. The docker command line running on the Github runner seems to be unable to pull the non-amd64 images, despite me setting up QEMU and Buildx in the workflow. Any ideas how I can fix this?

This is the error log for the part of the workflow that fails:

```
Run docker pull ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:unarr-amd64
  docker pull ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:unarr-amd64
  docker pull ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:unarr-arm64v8
  docker pull ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:unarr-arm32v7
  docker pull ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:latest-amd64
  docker pull ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:latest-arm64v8
  docker pull ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:latest-arm32v7
  docker pull ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:p7zip-amd64
  docker pull ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:p7zip-arm64v8
  docker pull ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:p7zip-arm32v7
  docker manifest create ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:unarr ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:unarr-amd64 ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:unarr-arm64v8 ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:unarr-arm32v7
  docker manifest annotate ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:unarr ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:unarr-amd64 --arch amd64
  docker manifest annotate ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:unarr ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:unarr-arm64v8 --arch arm64
  docker manifest annotate ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:unarr ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:unarr-arm32v7 --arch arm
  docker manifest push ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:unarr
  docker manifest create ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:p7zip ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:p7zip-amd64 ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:p7zip-arm64v8 ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:p7zip-arm32v7
  docker manifest annotate ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:p7zip ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:p7zip-amd64 --arch amd64
  docker manifest annotate ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:p7zip ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:p7zip-arm64v8 --arch arm64
  docker manifest annotate ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:p7zip ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:p7zip-arm32v7 --arch arm
  docker manifest push ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:p7zip
  docker manifest create ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:latest ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:latest-amd64 ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:latest-arm64v8 ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:latest-arm32v7
  docker manifest annotate ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:latest ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:latest-amd64 --arch amd64
  docker manifest annotate ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:latest ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:latest-arm64v8 --arch arm64
  docker manifest annotate ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:latest ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:latest-arm32v7 --arch arm
  docker manifest push ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:latest
  docker pull ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:v1.4.0-amd64
  docker pull ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:v1.4.0-arm64v8
  docker pull ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:v1.4.0-arm32v7
  docker manifest create ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:v1.4.0 ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:v1.4.0-amd64 ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:v1.4.0-arm64v8 ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:v1.4.0-arm32v7
  docker manifest annotate ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:v1.4.0 ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:v1.4.0-amd64 --arch amd64
  docker manifest annotate ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:v1.4.0 ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:v1.4.0-arm64v8 --arch arm64
  docker manifest annotate ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:v1.4.0 ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:v1.4.0-arm32v7 --arch arm
  docker manifest push ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:v1.4.0
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    DOCKERHUB_SLUG: ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker
    GHCR_SLUG: ghcr.io/***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker
    DOCKER_METADATA_OUTPUT_VERSION: v1.4.0
    DOCKER_METADATA_OUTPUT_TAGS: ghcr.io/***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:v1.4.0
    DOCKER_METADATA_OUTPUT_LABELS: org.opencontainers.image.title=yacreaderlibrary-server-docker
  org.opencontainers.image.description=Docker image running a headless version of YACReaderLibraryServer 
  org.opencontainers.image.url=https://github.com/***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker
  org.opencontainers.image.source=https://github.com/***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker
  org.opencontainers.image.version=v1.4.0
  org.opencontainers.image.created=2023-03-31T17:49:43.131Z
  org.opencontainers.image.revision=6b991e77e2d8b4ca51eec334f3ea18cf3d9b2aba
  org.opencontainers.image.licenses=GPL-3.0
    DOCKER_METADATA_OUTPUT_JSON: {"tags":["ghcr.io/***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:v1.4.0"],"labels":{"org.opencontainers.image.title":"yacreaderlibrary-server-docker","org.opencontainers.image.description":"Docker image running a headless version of YACReaderLibraryServer ","org.opencontainers.image.url":"https://github.com/***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker","org.opencontainers.image.source":"https://github.com/***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker","org.opencontainers.image.version":"v1.4.0","org.opencontainers.image.created":"2023-03-31T17:49:43.131Z","org.opencontainers.image.revision":"6b991e77e2d8b4ca51eec334f3ea18cf3d9b2aba","org.opencontainers.image.licenses":"GPL-3.0"}}
    DOCKER_METADATA_OUTPUT_BAKE_FILE: /tmp/docker-metadata-action-QrbYCu/docker-metadata-action-bake.json
unarr-amd64: Pulling from ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker
38a8b9979b0c: Pulling fs layer
48f754c837b5: Pulling fs layer
e62f0384a36b: Pulling fs layer
776e56018534: Pulling fs layer
22883c3dda69: Pulling fs layer
2d428c86948e: Pulling fs layer
22b0bae01498: Pulling fs layer
776e56018534: Waiting
22883c3dda69: Waiting
22b0bae01498: Waiting
2d428c86948e: Waiting
48f754c837b5: Verifying Checksum
48f754c837b5: Download complete
e62f0384a36b: Download complete
22883c3dda69: Verifying Checksum
22883c3dda69: Download complete
776e56018534: Verifying Checksum
776e56018534: Download complete
38a8b9979b0c: Verifying Checksum
38a8b9979b0c: Download complete
22b0bae01498: Verifying Checksum
22b0bae01498: Download complete
38a8b9979b0c: Pull complete
48f754c837b5: Pull complete
e62f0384a36b: Pull complete
2d428c86948e: Verifying Checksum
2d428c86948e: Download complete
776e56018534: Pull complete
22883c3dda69: Pull complete
2d428c86948e: Pull complete
22b0bae01498: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:c9ec7712740535ef92317ee93626cbd46e2a0c369a034799e3707558fa6899da
Status: Downloaded newer image for ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:unarr-amd64
docker.io/***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:unarr-amd64
unarr-arm64v8: Pulling from ***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker
no matching manifest for linux/amd64 in the manifest list entries
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

And this is my workflow:

```
---
# Builds our multi-arch Docker images for p7zip and unarr versions of YACReaderLibraryServer
name: Build and push images
on:
  release:
    types: [published]  
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  DOCKERHUB_SLUG: xthursdayx/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker
  GHCR_SLUG: ghcr.io/xthursdayx/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker

jobs:
  build-unarr-amd64:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: write
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        
      - name: Docker meta
        id: dh-meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@v4
        with:
          images: |
            ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}
          flavor: latest=false
          tags: |
            type=ref,event=tag
      - name: Docker meta
        id: gh-meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@v4
        with:
          images: |
            ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}
          flavor: latest=false
          tags: |
            type=ref,event=tag
      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2

      - name: Login to Dockerhub
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          registry: docker.io
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Login to GitHub Container Registry
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          registry: ghcr.io
          username: ${{ github.repository_owner }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Build and push container image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
        with:
          context: unarr
          file: unarr/Dockerfile
          platforms: linux/amd64
          push: true
          tags: |
            ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:unarr-amd64
            ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:latest-amd64
            ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:unarr-amd64
            ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:latest-amd64
            ${{ steps.dh-meta.outputs.tags }}-amd64
            ${{ steps.gh-meta.outputs.tags }}-amd64
          labels: ${{ steps.dh-meta.outputs.labels }}

  build-unarr-arm64v8:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: write
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Docker meta
        id: dh-meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@v4
        with:
          images: |
            ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}
          flavor: latest=false
          tags: |
            type=ref,event=tag
      - name: Docker meta
        id: gh-meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@v4
        with:
          images: |
            ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}
          flavor: latest=false
          tags: |
            type=ref,event=tag
      - name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v2

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2

      - name: Login to Dockerhub
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          registry: docker.io
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Login to GitHub Container Registry
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          registry: ghcr.io
          username: ${{ github.repository_owner }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Build and push container image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
        with:
          push: true
          context: unarr
          file: unarr/Dockerfile.aarch64
          platforms: linux/arm64/v8
          tags: |
            ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:unarr-arm64v8
            ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:latest-arm64v8
            ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:unarr-arm64v8
            ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:latest-arm64v8
            ${{ steps.dh-meta.outputs.tags }}-arm64v8
            ${{ steps.gh-meta.outputs.tags }}-arm64v8
          labels: ${{ steps.dh-meta.outputs.labels }}

  build-unarr-arm32v7:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: write
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Docker meta
        id: dh-meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@v4
        with:
          images: |
            ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}
          flavor: latest=false
          tags: |
            type=ref,event=tag
      - name: Docker meta
        id: gh-meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@v4
        with:
          images: |
            ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}
          flavor: latest=false
          tags: |
            type=ref,event=tag
      - name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v2

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2

      - name: Login to Dockerhub
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          registry: docker.io
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Login to GitHub Container Registry
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          registry: ghcr.io
          username: ${{ github.repository_owner }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Build and push container image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
        with:
          push: true
          context: unarr
          file: unarr/Dockerfile.armhf
          platforms: linux/arm/v7
          tags: |
            ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:unarr-arm32v7
            ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:latest-arm32v7
            ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:unarr-arm32v7
            ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:latest-arm32v7
            ${{ steps.dh-meta.outputs.tags }}-arm32v7
            ${{ steps.gh-meta.outputs.tags }}-arm32v7
          labels: ${{ steps.dh-meta.outputs.labels }}

  build-p7zip-amd64:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: write
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2

      - name: Login to Dockerhub
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          registry: docker.io
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Login to GitHub Container Registry
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          registry: ghcr.io
          username: ${{ github.repository_owner }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Build and push container image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
        with:
          push: true
          context: p7zip
          file: p7zip/Dockerfile
          platforms: linux/amd64
          tags: |
            ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:p7zip-amd64
            ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:p7zip-amd64
  build-p7zip-arm64v8:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: write
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v2

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2

      - name: Login to Dockerhub
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          registry: docker.io
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Login to GitHub Container Registry
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          registry: ghcr.io
          username: ${{ github.repository_owner }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Build and push container image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
        with:
          push: true
          context: p7zip
          file: p7zip/Dockerfile.aarch64
          platforms: linux/arm64/v8
          tags: |
            ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:p7zip-arm64v8
            ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:p7zip-arm64v8
  build-p7zip-arm32v7:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: write
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v2

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2

      - name: Login to Dockerhub
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          registry: docker.io
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Login to GitHub Container Registry
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          registry: ghcr.io
          username: ${{ github.repository_owner }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Build and push container image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
        with:
          push: true
          context: p7zip
          file: p7zip/Dockerfile.armhf
          platforms: linux/arm/v7
          tags: |
            ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:p7zip-arm32v7
            ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:p7zip-arm32v7
  push-manifest:
    needs: [build-unarr-amd64, build-unarr-arm64v8, build-unarr-arm32v7, build-p7zip-amd64, build-p7zip-arm64v8, build-p7zip-arm32v7]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Docker meta
        id: dh-meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@v4
        with:
          images: |
            ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}
          flavor: latest=false
          tags: |
            type=ref,event=tag
      - name: Docker meta
        id: gh-meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@v4
        with:
          images: |
            ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}
          flavor: latest=false
          tags: |
            type=ref,event=tag
      - name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v2
    
      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2

      - name: Login to Dockerhub
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          registry: docker.io
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Login to GitHub Container Registry
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          registry: ghcr.io
          username: ${{ github.repository_owner }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Create manifest for multi-arch images @ Docker Hub
        run: |
          docker pull ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:unarr-amd64
          docker pull ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:unarr-arm64v8
          docker pull ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:unarr-arm32v7
          docker pull ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:latest-amd64
          docker pull ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:latest-arm64v8
          docker pull ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:latest-arm32v7
          docker pull ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:p7zip-amd64
          docker pull ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:p7zip-arm64v8
          docker pull ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:p7zip-arm32v7
          docker manifest create ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:unarr ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:unarr-amd64 ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:unarr-arm64v8 ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:unarr-arm32v7
          docker manifest annotate ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:unarr ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:unarr-amd64 --arch amd64
          docker manifest annotate ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:unarr ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:unarr-arm64v8 --arch arm64
          docker manifest annotate ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:unarr ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:unarr-arm32v7 --arch arm
          docker manifest push ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:unarr
          docker manifest create ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:p7zip ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:p7zip-amd64 ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:p7zip-arm64v8 ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:p7zip-arm32v7
          docker manifest annotate ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:p7zip ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:p7zip-amd64 --arch amd64
          docker manifest annotate ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:p7zip ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:p7zip-arm64v8 --arch arm64
          docker manifest annotate ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:p7zip ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:p7zip-arm32v7 --arch arm
          docker manifest push ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:p7zip
          docker manifest create ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:latest ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:latest-amd64 ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:latest-arm64v8 ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:latest-arm32v7
          docker manifest annotate ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:latest ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:latest-amd64 --arch amd64
          docker manifest annotate ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:latest ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:latest-arm64v8 --arch arm64
          docker manifest annotate ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:latest ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:latest-arm32v7 --arch arm
          docker manifest push ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:latest
          docker pull ${{ steps.dh-meta.outputs.tags }}-amd64
          docker pull ${{ steps.dh-meta.outputs.tags }}-arm64v8
          docker pull ${{ steps.dh-meta.outputs.tags }}-arm32v7
          docker manifest create ${{ steps.dh-meta.outputs.tags }} ${{ steps.dh-meta.outputs.tags }}-amd64 ${{ steps.dh-meta.outputs.tags }}-arm64v8 ${{ steps.dh-meta.outputs.tags }}-arm32v7
          docker manifest annotate ${{ steps.dh-meta.outputs.tags }} ${{ steps.dh-meta.outputs.tags }}-amd64 --arch amd64
          docker manifest annotate ${{ steps.dh-meta.outputs.tags }} ${{ steps.dh-meta.outputs.tags }}-arm64v8 --arch arm64
          docker manifest annotate ${{ steps.dh-meta.outputs.tags }} ${{ steps.dh-meta.outputs.tags }}-arm32v7 --arch arm
          docker manifest push ${{ steps.dh-meta.outputs.tags }}
      - name: Create manifest for multi-arch images @ GHCR
        run: |
          docker pull ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:unarr-amd64
          docker pull ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:unarr-arm64v8
          docker pull ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:unarr-arm32v7
          docker pull ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:latest-amd64
          docker pull ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:latest-arm64v8
          docker pull ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:latest-arm32v7
          docker pull ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:p7zip-amd64
          docker pull ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:p7zip-arm64v8
          docker pull ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:p7zip-arm32v7
          docker manifest create ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:unarr ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:unarr-amd64 ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:unarr-arm64v8 ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:unarr-arm32v7
          docker manifest annotate ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:unarr ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:unarr-amd64 --arch amd64
          docker manifest annotate ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:unarr ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:unarr-arm64v8 --arch arm64
          docker manifest annotate ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:unarr ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:unarr-arm32v7 --arch arm
          docker manifest push ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:unarr
          docker manifest create ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:p7zip ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:p7zip-amd64 ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:p7zip-arm64v8 ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:p7zip-arm32v7
          docker manifest annotate ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:p7zip ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:p7zip-amd64 --arch amd64
          docker manifest annotate ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:p7zip ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:p7zip-arm64v8 --arch arm64
          docker manifest annotate ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:p7zip ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:p7zip-arm32v7 --arch arm
          docker manifest push ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:p7zip
          docker manifest create ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:latest ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:latest-amd64 ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:latest-arm64v8 ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:latest-arm32v7
          docker manifest annotate ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:latest ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:latest-amd64 --arch amd64
          docker manifest annotate ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:latest ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:latest-arm64v8 --arch arm64
          docker manifest annotate ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:latest ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:latest-arm32v7 --arch arm
          docker manifest push ${{ env.GHCR_SLUG }}:latest
          docker pull ${{ steps.gh-meta.outputs.tags }}-amd64
          docker pull ${{ steps.gh-meta.outputs.tags }}-arm64v8
          docker pull ${{ steps.gh-meta.outputs.tags }}-arm32v7
          docker manifest create ${{ steps.gh-meta.outputs.tags }} ${{ steps.gh-meta.outputs.tags }}-amd64 ${{ steps.gh-meta.outputs.tags }}-arm64v8 ${{ steps.gh-meta.outputs.tags }}-arm32v7
          docker manifest annotate ${{ steps.gh-meta.outputs.tags }} ${{ steps.gh-meta.outputs.tags }}-amd64 --arch amd64
          docker manifest annotate ${{ steps.gh-meta.outputs.tags }} ${{ steps.gh-meta.outputs.tags }}-arm64v8 --arch arm64
          docker manifest annotate ${{ steps.gh-meta.outputs.tags }} ${{ steps.gh-meta.outputs.tags }}-arm32v7 --arch arm
          docker manifest push ${{ steps.gh-meta.outputs.tags }}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is triggered by the way docker added [attestation metadata](https://docs.docker.com/build/attestations/) to images. By switching from an image manifest to a multi-platform manifest with a single platform image and an attestation for the `unknown/unknown` platform, a docker pull from a different platform will no longer work without additional options.

You can:

1. Turn off the attestation generation (I believe that is `attests: false` on every build, see the options in the [build-push-action](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action#inputs)).
2. Pull the images by platform using `--platform ...` on each pull.
3. Refactor the builds so you can run a single build for all platforms (docker has a [2 platform example](https://docs.docker.com/build/ci/github-actions/multi-platform/) that shows how you list each platform to build with a comma separated list).

Personally I'd opt for method 3 since it's a lot cleaner, but that's going to need some redesign of your Dockerfiles so they aren't platform specific.

I also write a tool called regclient, and the `regctl index create` command with a list of `--ref` and `--platform` options would probably be faster since it would avoid the pull (all the blobs remain on the registry).

Comment: Thanks for the help @BMitch 

For now I've tried to follow method 2, based on the amount of work necessary to redesign my Dockerfiles. I added --platform to each step in the `push-manifest` section of my workflow - e.g. `docker pull --platform=linux/amd64 ${{ env.DOCKERHUB_SLUG }}:unarr-amd64` however, I'm now seeing this error at the point where the first local manifest is being created:  `docker.io/***/yacreaderlibrary-server-docker:unarr-amd64 is a manifest list
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.`

Comment: I haven't done much with the `docker manifest` command, but that error looks like it's checking the image on the registry rather than the one you pulled. The easy button for you will be option 1.